# npm start showing errors with code npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When i try to load a project that i downloaded from web, it shows below error. i tried clean cache and npm install but still showing below error.

```
> reactjs-basics@1.0.0 start D:\React\reactjs-basics-11-router
> npm run build


> reactjs-basics@1.0.0 build D:\React\reactjs-basics-11-router
> webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --history-api-fallback

Hash: e5125e0911e8a3ceea45
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 1807ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    bundle.js     1 MB       0  [emitted]  main
bundle.js.map  1.09 MB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 251 hidden modules
'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactjs-basics@1.0.0 build: `webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --history-api-fallback`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs-basics@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aqib.Saman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-29T06_47_07_547Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactjs-basics@1.0.0 start: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs-basics@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aqib.Saman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-29T06_47_07_609Z-debug.log
```

I tried by changing cp to copy as some says but then i get below error

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactjs-basics@1.0.0 build: `webpack -d && copy src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --history-api-fallback`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs-basics@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aqib.Saman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-29T08_03_45_949Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactjs-basics@1.0.0 start: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs-basics@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aqib.Saman\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-29T08_03_46_008Z-debug.log
```

Loos like something is wrong if anybody can help it will be much appreciative

Comment: What is `cp` in the following line: `webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --history-api-fallback` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is coming from the copy operation here `webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html`

I presume you are using a windows OS to run this code and there is no `cp` command in windows.

You should try replacing the above with this

```
     `webpack -d && copy src/index.html dist/index.html`
```